# Geting elevation data from online services in QGIS?

Tags: qgis, elevation

Is there a way to add an elevation data provider in QGIS - something like XYZ tiles connections?
There are many providers available online
(like this one - [Terrarium elevation data](https://s3.amazonaws.com/elevation-tiles-prod/terrarium/%7Bz%7D/%7Bx%7D/%7By%7D.png))
When I add them as XYZ tile connection, I can browse the map, but it is not recognized as elevation data, it is shown simply as a map

In Layer properties, it is shown `Could not determine raster data type`.

Comment: plugin https://plugins.qgis.org/plugins/elevation/ ?

Comment: the z in xyz is zoom level for raster datasets https://developers.planet.com/planetschool/xyz-tiles-and-slippy-maps/

Answer (score 1):

A Web Coverage Service (WCS) will give you actual values.

See this combined DEM of Australian elevation and bathymetry as an example:

http://services.ga.gov.au/gis/services/DEM_SRTM_1Second_over_Bathymetry_Topography/MapServer/WCSServer?request=GetCapabilities&service=WCS

Add in QGIS by `Layer -> Add Layer -> Add WCS Layer...`